# PublishSubject в Presenter

Tags: java, android, rxjava

`PublishSubject` получаю  посредством метода в `DbRepository`. Сам `DbRepository` `Singleton`

```
public PublishSubject<User> getUser() {
        return userSubject;
    }
```

Создаю слушатель на `PublishSubject` в `Presenter`

```
public void listenUser(){
        disposableBag.add(this.dbRepository.getUser().subscribe(user -> {
           // Действия
        }));
    }
```

Вызываю его в `Fragment`

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            presenter.listenUser();
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }
```

Уничтожаю его методом

```
public void unListen(){
    disposableBag.clear();
}
```

В фрагменте

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        presenter.unListen();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Проблема в том что когда первый раз захожу во фрагмент то инициализируется `Presenter` и я начинаю слушать `PublishSubject`, приходит последний `user`, все окей. Потом когда я нажимаю кнопку назад происходит `onDestroy`, подписка удаляется. При повторном входе в фрагмент опять же инициализируется `Presenter` , но `listenUser()` как будто игнорируется, последний `user` не приходит. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужно использовать [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) вместо `PublishSubject`. Когда вы вызываете `onNext()` у `PublishSubject` он отправит объект `User` только активным подписчикам. Если второй экземпляр презентера подпишется после того как уже был отправлен `User`, он получит `User` только когда вы снова вызовете `onNext()` в репозитории. `BehaviorSubject` же всегда отправляет последний элемент подписчикам в момент подписки, т.е. при повторном создании фрагмента, новый презентер получит ранее переданный в `BehaviorSubject` объект `User`.

[Статья с описанием видов Rx Subject](https://medium.com/@poudanen/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-%D0%B8-async-subject-35ad50cd1064)